# How should I set the Vulkan SDK environment variables?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, vulkan

The [Linux Getting Started Guide for the Vulkan SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/app/doc/latest/linux/getting_started.html) gives instructions for setting up the runtime environment to allow applications to see the local Vulkan SDK installation:

> Set up these variables in your environment after you have set your VULKAN_SDK variable:
>
> ```
> $ export PATH=$PATH:$VULKAN_SDK/bin
> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib
> $ export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
> ```

What am I supposed to do with these commands? Currently I just put them at the end of my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
$ tail -4 ~/.bashrc
VULKAN_SDK=~/vulkan/VulkanSDK/1.0.13.0/x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:$VULKAN_SDK/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

This has seemed to work so far, but doesn't this only set the variables in Bash? What if I'm using a different shell or an IDE?

Is this the way I should set the Vulkan SDK environment variables, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDK Versions prior to 1.0.13.0 used to copy the json files that define the layers to /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d.  This made it less necessary to set VK_LAYER_PATH.

Starting with 1.0.13.0, the SDK no longer puts files into system directories.  So instead of pointing to the json files in $VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d with VK_LAYER_PATH you can instead copy the contents of $VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d to ~/.local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d.

The Vulkan loader searches for layers in  ~/.local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d in addition to /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d and /usr/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d

Comment: So this eliminates the need to set `VK_LAYER_PATH` in `~/.bashrc`, correct? Is there any way that I can eliminate the need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well? (I tried removing the `export PATH=$PATH:$VULKAN_SDK/bin` part and it didn't seem to break anything, so I guess that's not necessary?)

Comment: Yes, that would eliminate the need to set `VK_LAYER_PATH`.  The downside is that if you install a new SDK, you'll need to remember to re-copy the json files to your .local.  Maybe a symlink in .local would avoid this.  And yes, you still need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` unless you copy the binaries to someplace in the default loader path.  One alternative to "installing" the binaries is to edit each json file, putting the full path name in the `library_path` member.

Comment: And you don't need to modify your `PATH` unless you'd like to invoke any of the executables in the `$VULKAN_SDK/bin` directory, such as vulkaninfo.

Comment: All right, thank you! It's great to have an answer from someone from LunarG. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to set your environment variables depends greatly on your use case, and what distro you are using. 
However, if you're running an IDE from an Ubuntu desktop, and you want these variables available globally, I would recommend placing them in your ~/.profile file, rather than ~/.bashrc.

~/.bashrc is sourced whenever you start a bash terminal, so will only work for tools that are run from the terminal, but not for tools that are started from the desktop launcher.

~/.profile, on the other hand, is sourced when you log in, so its variables are available globally, from the terminal AND the desktop.
However, for ~/.profile, you must log out and back in, for changes to take effect.

Alternatively, as ratchet freak said, most (but not all) IDE's provide their own facility for setting environment variables. This is true for Code::Blocks and Qt Creator, but NOT Android Studio.  So, personally, I still prefer placing them in ~/.profile.

Answer (score 0):

In an IDE there will be a way to set environment variables for the running program. Those settings are often found along with the command line arguments setting.

In the program itself you can use [setenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) in linux or [_putenv_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyw7eyfw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in windows before the vulkan loader gets loaded.

Comment: So there isn't a way to set the variables globally? Or is that just not recommended?

Comment: well in the batch file that runs on log-on or startup you can set the env var but it's not something that's recommended. [The more portable solution is to copy the layer manifest files (the jsons) to `~/.local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md#linux-1)

Comment: Could you add a more detailed explanation to your answer of how to set up the required layer manifest files?